# Vertical alignment of overline

Tags: vertical-alignment, overline

I would like to have the horizontal lines aligned vertically in next document

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$\overline{z\,z'} = \overline{z} \, \overline{z'}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The bar over z is lower than the others.
With `\vphantom`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$\overline{z\,z'} = \overline{\vphantom{z'}z\,z'}
  = \overline{\vphantom{z'}z} \, \overline{\vphantom{z'}z'}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

the two bars on the right are vertically aligned but they are not with the first bar.

1. Why are the rightmost bar too high?
2. How can I get the same height as the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\vphantom{z'}` is making a strut that is taller than the `z'` as superscripts under `\overline` are set in cramped style.

LuaTeX has a primitive to force cramped style but otherwise `mathtools` has a macro `\cramped` that forces essentially the same layout.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$\overline{z\,z'} = \overline{\vphantom{\cramped{z'}}z\,z'}
  = \overline{\vphantom{\cramped{z'}}z} \, \overline{\vphantom{\cramped{z'}}z'}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, I have created `\altoverline` to place the overlines a fixed height above the baseline.  The default selected here is `22pt`.  It can be overridden with an optional argument or by redefining `\altlineht`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\def\altlineht{22pt}
\newcommand\altoverline[2][\altlineht]{\sbox0{$#2$}%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{22pt}{#2}%
    {\rule{\wd0}{.5pt}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}%
}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$\altoverline{z\,z'} = \altoverline{z} \, \altoverline{z'}$
\end{document}
```

[image]