# Unpleasant amount of whitespace above overline with Palatino

Tags: spacing, xetex

I am using XeLaTeX with Palatino/Pagella. When using the `overline` command, the amount of whitespace above the letters is large enough to offset the entire line, which I find rather unpleasant, considering this doesn't seem to occur with other fonts (or at least isn't as noticable). Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{enumitem}


%load LaTeX text components before math math
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{zpltlf}% Roman font for use in math mode
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}% used only by \mathtt
\usepackage[type1]{cabin}% used only by \mathsf
\usepackage{amsthm}% load before newtxmath
\usepackage[bigdelims, varbb]{newpxmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondox, frak=boondox]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{bm}% load after all math to give access to bold math%Now load the otf text fonts using fontspec---won't affect math
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % process with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX} % this reads in TeXGyrePagellaX.fontspec

\begin{document}
Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function between two topological spaces $X, Y$. Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if for every set $A \subset X$, $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$, where $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$.
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: palatino]

whereas simply using Computer Modern gives us
[image: modern]

The change in spacing is much less apparent with Computer Modern. Is there a workaround to this (other than just using another font)?

Comment: Off-topic: You should replace `$f : X \rightarrow Y$` with `$f \colon X \rightarrow Y$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of interfering with adjacent lines, you can auto-smash it, as I do below.  More safe, however, would be to give it a different name, to use only when needed, such as `\soverline` (smashed-overline), in the manner of `\newcommand\soverline[1]{\smash{\overline{#1}}}`.

Werner rightly notes in a comment that one can get burned if care is not taken.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{enumitem}


%load LaTeX text components before math math
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{zpltlf}% Roman font for use in math mode
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}% used only by \mathtt
\usepackage[type1]{cabin}% used only by \mathsf
\usepackage{amsthm}% load before newtxmath
\usepackage[bigdelims, varbb]{newpxmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondox, frak=boondox]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{bm}% load after all math to give access to bold math%Now load the otf text fonts using fontspec---won't affect math
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} % process with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX} % this reads in TeXGyrePagellaX.fontspec
\let\svoverline\overline
\renewcommand\overline[1]{\smash{\svoverline{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function between two topological spaces $X, Y$. Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if for every set $A \subset X$, $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$, where $\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `smash`-command! That helps a lot. Is there a way of setting the overline to be slightly lower in general? I think this could make this solution look slightly less crowded.

Comment: @tolUene `\smash` is not a panacea, as it typesets as if it has zero height.  This can potentially cause vertical interference with surrounding material.  As to lowering the overline height, a different approach altogether might work...something along the lines of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614486/vertical-alignment-of-overline/614490#614490, but adjusting the offset.

Comment: @tolUene: Something like should be avoided: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD7km.png

Answer (score 4):

Rather than smashing formulas, I suggest to increase the baselineskip, which is usually beneficial with Palatino.

Maybe a mixture of the two methods would be good. Note that in the third example the typesetting is very tight and, in accordance with Murphy’s law, the overlines will clash with the above line.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%load LaTeX text components before math math
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}% used only by \mathtt
\usepackage[type1]{cabin}% used only by \mathsf
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[bigdelims, varbb]{newpxmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondox, frak=boondox]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeXGyrePagellaX}

\linespread{1.2}

\setlength{\lineskip}{20pt} % just to check that it doesn't enter the scene

\begin{document}

\textbf{This uses larger baseline skip}

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a function between two 
topological spaces $X, Y$. Show that $f$ is continuous 
if and only if for every set $A \subset X$, 
$f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$, where 
$\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$.

\bigskip

\linespread{1.1}\selectfont

\textbf{This uses not so large baseline skip and smashed formulas}

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a function between two 
topological spaces $X, Y$. Show that $f$ is continuous 
if and only if for every set $A \subset X$, 
\smash{$f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$}, where 
\smash{$\overline{A}$} denotes the closure of $A$.

\bigskip

\linespread{1}\selectfont

\textbf{This uses smashed formulas}

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a function between two 
topological spaces $X, Y$. Show that $f$ is continuous 
if and only if for every set $A \subset X$, 
\smash{$f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$}, where 
\smash{$\overline{A}$} denotes the closure of $A$.

\end{document}
```

[image]